# Magmi is cannot find multiple images

Tags: image, import, magento-1.7, magmi

I've Googled, and Stackoverflowed this to death (and checked the Wiki), but I can't find a solution to my problem :(

**Problem:**
With Magento Magmi: all products and single images are importing fine, the only catch is that Magmi throws the following error when I try to import multiple images (e.g. `/BJ977L.png,/BJ977R.png`):

> Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - /BJ977L.png,/BJ977R.png cannot be found in images path

Obviously I checked and the files are there... Also, if I change it to only reference one image, then it works. I find this *very* confusing.

The images are located in: media/import and the Magmi Image Plugin configuration reflects this. Also, if I move the images to another folder, say `var/import/images`; then it makes no difference...

Your help is hugely appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem: I'm adding all my primary images as field `image`, `small_image` and `thumbnail` and additional images in `image_gallery` separated with semi-colons `;`. However, I don't get an error, but I only see the first image.. very annoying too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Images Attribute Processor documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor) states, you should be using a semi-colon `;` to separate multiple images.

```
/extraimg1.jpg;/extraimg2.jpg
```

Also ensure that the column names you are using are correct.  `media_gallery` is the correct column header name for the media gallery images.

Comment: yes, I've tried it, still the same error though (using semi-colon now)

Comment: Should we set as many "media_gallery" columns as we have images in gallery? Or it should be one column for several images which are separated by ";" ?

Comment: Only one `media_gallery` column with images separated by a `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using semi colon?

```
/BJ977L.png;/BJ977R.png
```

Comment: no difference, I'm afraid. Am I maybe using the incorrect column names for images? 

using: gallery,image,small_image,thumbnail,_media_image

Comment: The column name for the media gallery is `media_gallery`

Comment: Thank you! It appears that I was using the wrong column names for the images (on top of separating my images with a comma instead of a semicolon). Incorrect columns used: gallery,image,small_image,thumbnail,_media_image. 
I have since moved all images to the new 'media_gallery' column and removed the rest of my images columns. 

Bam! Problem sorted! no more 'image not found' error! 
THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the complete file path to the images? Also, did you specify the file path root for the images in the plugin settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you have formatted the `.csv` file the right way then you should check the `Image Renaming` setting for the `Image attributes processor`. If you specify a bad rule to rename your newly imported images you could end up with the same name for every picture. So basically the first image will be imported, then the second will overwrite it because it was given the same name. If you only see the last picture you specified for the `media_gallery` attribute then this is probably the cause. 
Hope this helps.